# Anaconda Uninstall and .anaconda_backup

Tags: python, anaconda, uninstallation

I have followed the steps here (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) to do a full uninstall of Anaconda.

I didn't, however, delete the .anaconda_backup folder produced in the clean step before doing a simple uninstall. But can't find it if I search in my MAC finder. Does the simple remove this, or should I have manually deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the Anaconda Distribution software 3 or 4 times while intentionally leaving a few files behind (such as the .anaconda_backup folder you mentioned) and it didn't cause me any problems when I reinstalled it.

When I went back through my install directory for anaconda3 files, I **could not find the files I left behind**.
This means that leaving a few unimportant files behind won't affect the reinstallation of Anaconda or a different Python environment.

NOTE: This may differ for you because I use windows and you use OS X.

(I wanted to post this in a comment but Stack Overflow won't let me because I have low rep)